# Creating div with backgroundimage url from state programmatically

Tags: reactjs

I have a project where you can upload multiple images on form, if you upload one image it takes an div and uses state to add backgroundImage url of the uploaded image, to the div which is based off a grid.

My requirement would be how could I create a divs on the fly and append the urls as backgroundImage url from the state of the uploaded image?

Example: `<div style={{backgroundImage:`url(${this.state.url})`}} key={''}>{''}`

This works well, however I'd like to create divs on the fly, for example if you add new item, it adds a new div with backgroundImage url, and if there's multiple items, it would add multiple divs with corresponding urls to the backgroundImage property.

Here's my image upload component:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../App.css"
import uploadImages from './uploadImages'
class ImageUpload extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: '',
      url: "",
      progress: 0
    };
  }


  handleChange = e => {
    if (e.target.files) {
      const images = e.target.files;
      this.setState(() => ({ images }));
      console.log(images)
    }
  };
  handleUpload = () => {
    if(this.state.images.length === 0) return;        
    uploadImages(this.state.images, "images/", null).then(urls=>{
        this.setState( {url: urls[0]} );
      });
  }


  render() {

    return (

      <div>



         <div className="file-field input-field">
          <div className="btn">
          <input type="file" multiple onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
          <div className="file-path-wrapper">
            <input className="file-path validate" type="text" />
          </div>
    </div>
        <button
          onClick={this.handleUpload}
          className="additem"
        >
          Add Item
    </button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <main>
        <div class="grid">
        <div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${this.state.url})`}} key={''}>{''}
        </div> 


</div>

        </main>
      </div>


    );
  }
}

export default ImageUpload;
```

And this is my uploadImages component:

```
import storage from "../Firebase/index";

async function uploadImages(imageList, path, progressCallback) {
    var promises = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < imageList.length; i++) {
        var image = imageList[i];
        promises.push(uploadImage(image, path, progressCallback));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises);
}

async function uploadImage(image, path, progressCallback) {
  progressCallback = progressCallback || function() {};

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var task = storage.ref(`${path}${image.name}`).put(image);
      task.on("state_changed", progressCallback, reject, ()=>{
          resolve(task.snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL());
          console.log(image)
      });

  });
}

export default uploadImages;
```

Apologies if it's something basic, I'm fairly new to react and this seems to be puzzling.

Code update:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "../App.css"
import uploadImages from './uploadImages'
class ImageUpload extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      images: [{
        id: '',
        image: '',
        url: '',
        progress: 0,
      }],
    };
  }
  handleChange = e => {
    if (e.target.files) {
      const images = e.target.files;
      this.setState(() => ({ images }));
      console.log(images)
    }
  };



  handleUpload = () => {
    if(this.state.images.length === 0) return;
    // I left out the "progress" method because doing a progress over multiple
    // files is a bit more tricky. But if you do want to do that, you'll have
    // to either get the total file size added together, or you'll have to
    // create a progress callback for each image being uploaded
    uploadImages(this.state.images, "images/", null).then(urls=>{
        // this is a list of urls, so you'll need to do something with that.
        this.setState( {url: urls[0]} );
        console.log(urls)
      });
  }

  render() {
    const divWithBackgroundImage = this.state && this.state.images.map(image =>
      <div style={{backgroundImage:`url(${this.state.images.url})`}} key={''}></div> )
    return (

      <div>
         <div className="file-field input-field">
          <div className="btn">
          <input type="file" multiple onChange={this.handleChange} />
        </div>
          <div className="file-path-wrapper">
            <input className="file-path validate" type="text" />
          </div>
    </div>
        <button
          onClick={this.handleUpload}
          className="additem"
        >
          Add Item
          </button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <main>
        <div className="grid">

        { divWithBackgroundImage }
          </div>
        </main>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ImageUpload;
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe to create state array of uploaded images links, and then to map that array?

Comment: From seeing the code, I'm already updating the state with uploaded image urls.

Comment: You need to crate array of images in state : 
....
this.state = {
     images: [
             { id: ' '; image: ''', url:''. progress: 0 },
             { id: ' ', image: ''', url:''. progress: 0 },
             ...
         ],
    };

render() {

//Then map array: 

const divWithBackgroundImage = this.state.images.map(image =>

      <div style={{backgroundImage:url(image.url)}} key={''}></div>

)
return (

        ......
           <div class="grid">
                { divWithBackgroundImage }
        </div>
        ......
)}

Something like that

Comment: Thank you for your comment however your code returns an error that images.map is not a function.

Comment: I do see where you're aiming at, frankly that's what I've been doing and there's no progress as the error persists even with this.state && this.state.images.map.
I've updated my main post now.